# $ operator and mutate yield different results in r

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

Has anyone of you ever gotten different results when using the $ operator versus dplyr?

When I use this code:

```
Data_filtered_0<-Data_filtered_0%>%dplyr::mutate(sum_lag = lag(sum, n = 1, default = NA))
Data_filtered_0$sum_lag.gmc<-Data_filtered_0$sum_lag-mean(Data_filtered_0$sum_lag,na.rm=T)type here
```

versus this code:

```
Data_filtered_0<-Data_filtered_0%>%dplyr::mutate(sum_lag = lag(sum, n = 1, default = NA))%>%dplyr::mutate(sum_lag.gmc=sum_lag-mean(sum_lag,na.rm=T))type here
```

the variable Coefficients$sum_lag.gmc resulting from the following model has different values:

```
tres_rnt <- lme(sum ~ sum_lag.gmc,
               random =  ~ sum_lag.gmc | accountId,
               data = Data_filtered_0, 
               na.action="na.exclude")
Coefficients<-as.data.frame(coef(res_rnt), col.names=NULL)
Coefficients <- tibble::rownames_to_column(Coefficients, "accountId")ype here
```

I am really confused because I thought that both versions of the code - $operator and mutate - should produce identical results. Maybe there can be problems when useing mutate() two times in one step?

Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need to use two mutate calls.  You can do `mutate(var1 = 1:10, var2 = var1 + 1)` - the variables are created in order, so you can refer back to previous variables within the same call.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Could this be introduced by some randomness of `lme` (unclear what package this is from)? How much of a difference is there? Could it be a rounding issue?